# Elasticsearch All Shards failed on cluster with multiple nodes on Azure VM

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-virtual-machine

I have Elasticsearch cluster with 3 master nodes, 2 data nodes, and cluster node deployed on different Virtual Machine on Azure. It was working fine but suddenly it failed and now `[search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed` error coming when we are trying to search any data.
There are total 200+ indexes with all as **red** status.
Following is the health of the entire cluster

```
"status": "red",
    "timed_out": false,
    "number_of_nodes": 6,
    "number_of_data_nodes": 2,
    "active_primary_shards": 5,
    "active_shards": 10,
    "relocating_shards": 0,
    "initializing_shards": 0,
    "unassigned_shards": 524,
    "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
    "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
    "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
    "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
    "active_shards_percent_as_number": 1.8726591760299627
```

What could be the possible solution for this?
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the node is down for some reason or a few indexes in the node have been corrupted. First, find out the problematic node.

```
http://<yourhost>:9200/_cluster/health/?level=shards
```

Above command will give you the red node. Then go to that node, try to restart or list all the indexes in that node and find which one is red. Delete that index and search again. Lucene will take care of re-indexing when the search is hit after that.